# How to filter a JSON response and get needed data from it in react native?

Tags: react-native

Here is my JSON response.

```json
{
    {
      "tripDate": "2021-09-15",
      "totalFare": 337,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
        {
          "voidType": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "tripDate": "2021-09-13",
      "totalFare": 540,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
        {
          "voidType": 0
        },
        {
          "voidType": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "tripDate": "2021-09-12",
      "totalFare": 270,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
        {
          "voidType": 1
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

From the above response I need tripdate value when void type in tripLineItemDetails is zero, even if one of the object in tripLineItemDetails is zero I need that tripdate.Responce should be like this.

```
    {
  "tripDateLineItems": [
    {
      "tripDate": "2021-09-15",
      "totalFare": 337,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
        {
          "voidType": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "tripDate": "2021-09-13",
      "totalFare": 540,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
        {
          "voidType": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Add an expected result and a sample filter object

Comment: journeyList= {data.tripLineItemDetails.filter(x => x.voidType === '0')}. in data i am getting tripDateLineItems array.

Comment: need tripDate when VoidType in tripLineItemDetails is zero.  expected result is in above responce is should get tripdates 2021-09-15 and 2021-09-13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  const response = [{
      "tripDate": "2021-09-15",
      "totalFare": 337,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
        {
          "voidType": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "tripDate": "2021-09-13",
      "totalFare": 540,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
        {
          "voidType": 0
        },
        {
          "voidType": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "tripDate": "2021-09-12",
      "totalFare": 270,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
        {
          "voidType": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
const data = response.filter(obj => obj.tripLineItemDetails.find(o => o.voidType == 0));

//Here you'll receive your data with tripDate of voidType 0
console.log(data);
```

The result would be:

```js
[
  {
      "tripDate": "2021-09-15",
      "totalFare": 337,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
        {
          "voidType": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "tripDate": "2021-09-13",
      "totalFare": 540,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
      {
        "voidType": 0
      },
      {
        "voidType": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

With this logic, you'll also get `voidType: 1` where `voidType` would be `0`.

And if you don't want that `voidType: 1` then use other array function like `.map` OR `nested loop` logic like:

```js
if(data[i].tripLineItemDetails[j].voidType != 1){
   //then do this
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Hi it didn't worked for me I am getting response like this.  [ { tripDate: '2021-09-15',
        totalFare: 337,
        tripLineItemDetails: [ { voidType: 0 } ] },
      { tripDate: '2021-09-13',
        totalFare: 540,
        tripLineItemDetails: [ { voidType: 0 }, { voidType: 1 } ] } ]

Comment: After filtering I need data like this.  { "tripDateLineItems": [{
      "tripDate": "2021-09-15",
      "totalFare": 337,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
        {
          "voidType": 0
        }]},
    {
      "tripDate": "2021-09-13",
      "totalFare": 540,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
        {
          "voidType": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: @kumar, you have to use `.map` to @Shoaib Khan's answer and modify `tripLineItemDetails` field to only keep the `voidType: 0` item.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
      "tripDate": "2021-09-15",
      "totalFare": 337,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
        {
          "voidType": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "tripDate": "2021-09-13",
      "totalFare": 540,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
        {
          "voidType": 0
        },
        {
          "voidType": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "tripDate": "2021-09-12",
      "totalFare": 270,
      "tripLineItemDetails": [
        {
          "voidType": 1
        }
      ]
    }]

var data1 = data.filter(obj => obj.tripLineItemDetails.find(o => o.voidType == 0));
console.log(data1);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with an [edit] to add an explanation as to how the code you've written solves the question.